# migrate int id to uuid string using prisma

Tags: node.js, prisma

I want to my database column int id to string uuid format.

```
  id                   Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  // to
  id                   String               @id @default(uuid())
```

Rewriting prisma code Above, migration works but, the id just was stringified sequence like '1' or '2', and I want to reset id to uuid. But I didn't find this uuid function which algorithm derived from and architecture(where it derived from database, rust, or client?). What the best way to reassign id? I can generate uuid from node clients?

[In Addition]

I found explanation in [referred to document](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#uuid)
This is derived from prisma.

```
 You can still use uuid() when using introspection by manually 
 changing your Prisma schema and generating Prisma Client,
 in that case the values will be generated by Prisma's query engine.
```

but can we call it from client api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found prisma using uuid v4 as default, so any library or programming language is available as manner of how it generates.
I post [discussion thread](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/13827) in prisma repository, too.